# How to return 400 status in model validation spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, junit

I want to test my `StudentDTO` :

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentDTO {
@Id
private int studentId;
@NotNull
@Size(min=2,max=30,message = "Name should consist of 2 to 30 symbols!")
private String studentName;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 30,message = "Surname should consist of 2 to 30 symbols!")
private String studentSurname;
@NotNull
@Min(value = 10,message = "Student age should be more than 10!")
private int studentAge;
@NotNull
@Min(value = 1900,message = "Entry year should be more than 1900!")
@Max(value=2021,message = "Entry year should be less than 2021!")
private int entryYear;
@NotNull
@Min(value = 2020,message = "Graduate year should be not less than 2020!")
private int graduateYear;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 3,message = "Faculty name should consist of minimum 3 symbols!")
private String facultyName;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4,message = "Group name should consist of 4 symbols!")
@Size(max = 4)
private String groupName;
}
```

Method for testing in `StudentController` :

```
@PostMapping("successStudentAddition")
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid StudentDTO studentDTO, Errors errors, Model model) {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute(STUDENT_MODEL, studentDTO);
        return "/studentViews/addStudent";
    }

    Student student = new Student(studentDTO.getStudentId(), studentDTO.getStudentName(), studentDTO.getStudentSurname(),
            studentDTO.getStudentAge(), studentDTO.getEntryYear(), studentDTO.getGraduateYear(), studentDTO.getFacultyName(),
            groupService.getGroupIdByName(studentDTO.getGroupName()));
    studentService.addStudent(student);
    return "/studentViews/successStudentAddition";
}
```

I am trying to test in this way :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = StudentController.class)
class StudentControllerTest {
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@MockBean
private StudentController studentController;

@Test
void whenInputIsInvalid_thenReturnsStatus400() throws Exception {
    StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO();
    studentDTO.setStudentId(0);
    studentDTO.setStudentName("Sasha");
    studentDTO.setStudentSurname("Georginia");
    studentDTO.setStudentAge(0);
    studentDTO.setEntryYear(5);
    studentDTO.setGraduateYear(1);
    studentDTO.setFacultyName("facop");
    studentDTO.setGroupName("BIKS");

    mvc.perform(post("/studentViews/successStudentAddition")
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(model().attribute("student", studentDTO))
            .andDo(print());
}
}
```

In my test I got 200 error, but I need to get 400 error with determined error above on the field from my `StudentDTO`.

e.g. if I pass `studentAge = 5`, I should to get 400 error and the message : `Student age should be more than 10!` like in the `StudentDTO`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have such a condition, Spring will throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. To handle these exceptions you can write a class with `@ControllerAdvice`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {
     

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Error> invalidArgumentExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
// Instead of "/studentViews/successStudentAddition" you can return to some generic error page.
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("/studentViews/successStudentAddition", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often turn to spring's *org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity* [class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html).

```
@PostMapping("successStudentAddition")
public ResponseEntity<String> addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid StudentDTO studentDTO, Errors errors, Model model) {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute(STUDENT_MODEL, studentDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("/studentViews/addStudent", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    Student student = new Student(studentDTO.getStudentId(), studentDTO.getStudentName(), studentDTO.getStudentSurname(),
            studentDTO.getStudentAge(), studentDTO.getEntryYear(), studentDTO.getGraduateYear(), studentDTO.getFacultyName(),
            groupService.getGroupIdByName(studentDTO.getGroupName()));
    studentService.addStudent(student);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("/studentViews/successStudentAddition", HttpStatus.Ok);
}
```

Comment: Okay,but I need to test this validation)
How can I do it?